# CSS: How to target a specific cell inside a table?

Tags: css, css-selectors, html-table

I have a dynamically generated table and I need to style differently the 5th cell from the first row of that table.

I´m able to style the first row via:

```
//table.css

.mytable tbody tr:first-child { whatever styles I define.. }
```

Or the 5th column via:

```
.mytable tbody td:nth-child(5) { whatever styles I define.. }
```

I tried to combine this two selectors so that the cell in the 1st row, 5th column is different but without success. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can simply use the below selector

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/HMMvg/)

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/HMMvg/2/) (Multiple Rows)

```
.mytable tbody tr:first-child td:nth-child(5) {
   /* Styles goes here */
}
```

Explanation : The above selector selects 5th `td` element which is nested under 1st `tr` element which is further nested under `tbody` which is further nested under ANY element having class `.mytable` but obviously, `tbody` will be used inside a `table` but if you want to make it specific, you can change this `.mytable` to `table.mytable`

Or you can use

```
.mytable tbody tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(5) {
   /* Styles goes here */
}
```

Explanation: Same as above, using `nth` instead of `first-child`

Comment: actually `tbody` is not needed if the table has not a `thead` and `tfooter`

Comment: @FezVrasta Well, am not aware how the table structure is, I just made that out from the selector he used

Comment: thanks man, works like a charm! I was complicating the combination between these two elements tr:first-child td:nth-child(5)